# Java strange behavior when delete nested folders which is opened in Windows Explorer

Tags: java, file, io

I have a folder structure like this (without any files for simple test):

> **D:\A**\B\C

now I want to delete **D:\A**, the standard/traditional way is using recursion to delete sub files/folders before delete parent folder:

```
public static void delete(File file) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            file.delete();
        } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
            File subs[] = file.listFiles();
            if (null == subs) {
                return;
            }
            for (File sub : subs) {
                delete(sub);
            }
            if (file.delete()) {
                System.out.println("Delete OK: " + file);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Delete Fail: " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " => " + Arrays.toString(file.listFiles()));
            }
        }
    }
```

When I call below code, it's OK:

```
delete(new File("D:\\A"));
```

But when I open the path **D:\A\B\C** in **Windows Explorer** and try to run, here is the result (90% times, but about 10% it's OK):

```
Delete OK: D:\A\B\C
Delete Fail: D:\A\B => children:[D:\A\B\C]
Delete Fail: D:\A => children:[D:\A\B]
```

It's very strange when **D:\A\B\C** is deleted, but after that I still get the **D:\A\B\C** as the children of **D:\A\B**

Can I consider this is a JRE bug? I am using Windows 10 64bit, JDK 8.

Comment: Hmm, looks like a race condition. A/B/C is being deleted, but deletion would not be complete at the time you try to delete A/B. You could try to add some delay to make sure.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I know delay will make it run, but the delete method has return result, it returns true it means the file is deleted

Comment: You you have any background process that scans the disk?

Comment: @MauricePerry I have not, I turn off anti-virus, too

Comment: I believe this is actually a Windows bug.  The operating system reports that the file has been deleted, a few milliseconds before the file has actually gone.

Answer (score 1):

I also think file.delete() has some issue with windows permission, could you try Files.delete(path) for workaround